# MVC3 - Dynamic URL redirect in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, url, redirect, razor

I am using C#, MVC3, and Razor.

I have a javascript function (in the view) that gets called when a particular menu item is clicked. In this function, I need to build a new URL with parameters (based on other selections on the screen) and redirect to it. It want it to do something like this:

ValueA and ValueB are variables in the javascript section and are populated with values.

```
function doSomething(ID) {
    location.href =  "../Area/Controller/Action?ID=" + ID + "&ValueA=" + ValueA + "&ValueB=" + ValueB;
  }
```

However, due to the nature of MVC I need to make sure the URL is always right, regardless of how the user got to the page. I've tried to use @Url.Content("") (see next code block) but the issue I run into is:

- The name 'ID' does not exist in the current context
- The name 'ValueA' does not exist in the current context
- The name 'ValueB' does not exist in the current context

Here is an example of what I would like to do but get the above mentioned errors on:

```
function doSomething(ID) {
    location.href = @Url.Content("~/Area/Controller/Action?ID=" + ID + "&ValueA=" + ValueA + "&ValueB=" + ValueB);
  }
```

How can I make this work? Is there a better way?

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should concatenate the the static part to the dynamic part:

```
location = "@Url.Content("~/Area/Controller/Action")?ID=" + ID + "&ValueA=" + ValueA + "&ValueB=" + ValueB;
```

The outer `"@...?ID="` is a Javascript string literal.
`@Url.Content("...")` is server-side code that emits raw text into the Javascript literal.

Comment: Works great! This makes a lot of sense. I'm wishing I had thought of it.

Comment: BTW, you should call `@Url.Action` instead of `Content`.

Comment: Thanks. I've modified the code to use `@Url.Action` since it is in the same controller as the current view. Works great.